# Not Enough Items (Minecraft 1.6.4) Not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I click on cheat mode in my game, it tells me it is selected, but it is always recipe mode. Even though the selection in the config is set to -1

Comment: Are you on a server?

Comment: No I am not on a server